# UIScrollView, переопределение стандартной функции анимации

Tags: ios, ios7

Можно ли у `UIScrollView` переопределить стандартную функцию анимации скролла?

Пишу красивый PagingScrollView с трансформацией страничек - странички меняют свои размеры в процессе скролла. Сейчас анимированая трансформация

```
page.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

происходит в методе

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

графика заметно лагает, думаю это из за одновременной анимации скролла и трансформации, можно ли это исправить?
[image]

Comment: Ох и наешься ты с UIScrollView... По какой-то великой мысли, анимация в этом методе сделана не потоково, а "линейно" (сам вот буквально мучился почти месяц с этим чудом), то есть пока Эплавская анимация не отработает, все остальное будет "лагать" и "тупить".
Не проще использовать UIControlView ? Мне кажется это будет удобнее...

Comment: @dark_Haron у `UICollectionView` надо будет поведение paging-a самому реализовывать, но этот вариант тоже рассмотрю, спасибо

Comment: родилась еще идея, надо будет дома посмотреть: Что если стандартную анимацию отключить и самому обработчик анимации написать? Наверняка в делегатах метода можно поискать что-нибуть на эту тему.

Comment: для UICollectionView попробуйте засабклассить UICollectionViewFlowLayout, решение может быть там

Comment: @dark_Haron, @iFreeman пропустил программу через профайлер и обнаружил что `UIWebViewTouchEventsGestureRecognizer` съедает 15% времени выполнения , отключение `userIteraction` у страничек на время скролла дает значительный прирост производительности

Comment: @dark_Haron если самому писать обработчик анимации то получится [iCarousel][1], сложная штука, пока опыта не достаточно для подобных вещей


  [1]: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: я вижу у тебя скругленные углы. Попробуй убрать их. Просто анимация с cornerRadius очень неэффективно работает. Если дело именно в углах и cornerRadius, то придется искать другой способ изобразить скругленные углы. Это простая задача на смекалку.

Comment: Смотря на скрин хочется посоветовать `UIPageController`, там можно и анимацию свою навернуть при желании.

Answer (score 1):

Советую обратить внимание на вот это решение
[ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView](https://github.com/ikemai/ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView)